# ESLint: Disable all default rules

Tags: eslint

How to disable all default rules in ESLint? It shows on this page http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface that you can use `--reset` but when I do so:

```
$ eslint --global globalVar --reset --rule 'no-undef: 2' main.js
Invalid option '--reset' - perhaps you meant '--quiet'?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using eslint version `<=0.24.1` then you can use `--reset` flag to turn off all the rules but if you using the `1.0.0-rc-1` then all the rules are by default off and the reset flag has been removed.

check your version using `eslint -v`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I saw using `1.0.0-rc-1`. Nevertheless I had already used the `config.json` present in the eslint directory and disabled all rules